# Put style in Data table

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, datatable

Everyone!

I have a label where I store my database row value. What I want is to make it displayed like below.

```
<li> Row value 1</li>
<li> Row value 2</li>
<li> Row value 3</li>
```

Here is what I have so far.

**Front End **

**Backend**

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("myconnectionhere")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("myselect command", conn)
        'Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Resulttext.Text = dt.Rows(i)("Name").ToString &  Resulttext.Text 
            Next
            conn.Close()
        End If
```

The query is retrieving more than one rows. 
The codes are working. Only I'm asking for a style. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at something like this?

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   Resulttext.Text = "<ul>"
   For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
       Resulttext.Text = "<li>" & dt.Rows(i)("Name").ToString & "</li>" &  Resulttext.Text  
   Next
   Resulttext.Text = "</ul>"
   conn.Close()
   End If
```

Comment: Hi @ArunGeorge. Already resolve the problem. We have the same solution. Thank you! :) Still marking this as an answer!